# scanf setting value on erroneous input

Tags: c

I wrote an easy code and I got a question , here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int first = 0;   
  int second = 0;

  printf("please enter two integers to determine their relation:  \n");
  scanf("%d %d",&first , &second);
  if ( first == second)
  {
    printf("%d and %d are equal\n", first ,second);
  }

  else if (first > second) 
  {
    printf("%d is bigger than %d \n" ,first ,second);
  }
  else if (first < second)
  {
    printf("%d is smaller than %d \n" ,first ,second);   
  }
  else
  {
    printf("something is wrong \n");`
  }
  system("pause");``
  return 0;
}
```

now when I entered a character I thought I will get some error but instead after I put it in it returns 0 equal to 0,
why?

Comment: I just fell between the lines.

Comment: In the future, *please properly format your code* (I just did this for you). As posted originally, it was impossible to read.

Comment: Also - probably best not to call it "easy code" when it's only a dozen lines of code and you can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: And one more thing: Please edit your question to show what you actually entered as input (I don't know what you mean when you say you "entered a character", especially since your program is asking for two values).

Comment: When a character which can not be interpreted as a numerical value is input, it is not accepted and the value is not set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> now when I entered a character I thought I will get some error but instead after I put it in it returns 0 equal to 0, why?

You *did* get an error, but you ignored it.  The return value of `scanf()`, if non-negative, tells you how many input fields were successfully converted and assigned.  In the event that the input cannot be matched to the pattern, you have a *matching failure*.  Provided that that occurs at a point in the pattern preceding at least one input field directive, that will result in fewer fields being assigned than there are in the format.  You could have detected that via `scanf()`'s return value if you had bothered to check it.

C was designed for system programming.  It does not call for unsolicited runtime messages to to be emitted, and it does not make assumptions about what programs should do in the event of unexpected input or other errors.  It gives you the information you need to direct the response of your choice, or, indeed, to direct no explicit response whatever.

In the program presented, your choice is to ignore the error.  In the event of a matching failure such as you describe, any variables that were not assigned values by `scanf()` retain the values they had before the `scanf()` call, so ignoring the error produces the same behavior as the user entering "0 0".

Comment: thank you for the explanation, about the code formatting sorry I'm new here and I thought it was fine, I will try better next time

Comment: @rubhani, if you are satisfied that this answer adequately addresses your question then do consider clicking the the check mark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.  It is conventional and expected here that you will choose one of the answers in this way (and at the moment, there aren't any others).